# How to enable GD work with PHP5?

Tags: php, linux, gd, slackware

When I look into the phpinfo page I can't find GD... And also It looks enabled in my php.ini file but don't work. Anyone know solution?

I use Slackware 14.1 Linux.

This I get when run php -v

php -v

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib64/php/extensions/gd.so' - libX11.so.6: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 PHP
>   Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib64/php/extensions/php_gd2.dll' -
>   /usr/lib64/php/extensions/php_gd2.dll: cannot open shared object file:
>   No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 PHP 5.4.32 (cli)
>   (built: Sep  4 2014 14:06:18)  Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
>       with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.7.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd.

Comment: What OS are you using?  For most linux distros you have to install this separately.  Look for a package called php5-gd or similar.

Comment: Make sure the gd so file is being loaded in the php.ini extensions format

Comment: How to install it for Slackware 14.1 ?

Comment: Only windows uses `php_gd2.dll` (`.dll`) files right?

Comment: You can also run trought Linux, I enabled it in php.ini to try solve problem.